# Laravel Join 2 tables , one data from first table and multiple row from second table

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

> FirstTable
>
> id   |   name   |
>
> ---
>
> 1   | student1 |
>
> 2   | student2 |
>
> 3   | student3 |
>
> 4   | student4 |

==============================

> SecondTable
>
> Id | stud_id | subject | mark
>
> ---
>
> 1  |  1     | maths   | 50
>
> 2  |  1     | english   | 45
>
> 3  |  2     | maths   | 20
>
> 4  |  3     | maths   | 40

How would i query  in laravel with the above table structure.. 
i need outpus as

```
{

    "id": 1,

    "name":"student1"

    "marks":[

        {

            "subject":"maths",

            "marks":50,

        },

        {

            "subject":"emglish",

            "marks":45,

        }

    ]

}
```

Comment: do you want query using laravel query builder or laravel eloquent ORM ?

Comment: anything is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done it in Laravel Query Builder.
Please see  below.

```
$stud = DB::table('FirstTable')
               ->join('SecondTable','FirstTable.id','=','SecondTable.stud_id')
               ->where('FirstTable.id','=','1')
               ->get();
dd($stud);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in laravel eloquent way. In your Student model create relationship method. It is a student can have many  subject relationship

```
public function subject(){
return $this->hasMany('App\"the second table model name",'stud_id');
```

}

then you in controller you can access it like

```
public function index(){
$student = Student::find("Student_id")->subject;
dd($student);
}
```

please read the documentation for better understanding 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 0):

You can create a relationships with these tables. In here you need that one to many relationships.

You need students , lessons tables

Students

```
Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('student_name')
});
```

Lessons

```
Schema::create('lessons', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('student_id');
$table->integer('exam_number'); // there will be many exams right ?
$table->integer('lesson1')
$table->integer('lesson2');
$table->integer('lesson-etc');
$table->timestamps();

$table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')
});
```

Then edit your models as below

Student model;

```
public function lessons(){

       return $this->hasMany('App\Lesson','student_id','id');
    }
```

and in your lessons model;

```
 public function students(){

      return $this->belongsTo('App\Student');
    }
```

Then in your controller,

```
$students = Student::whereHas('lessons', function ($query) {

            $query->where("exam_number", 2 (or which exam));
        })->get();
```

Finally, in your blade;

```
 <table >
  <tr>
    <th>Student Name</th>
    <th>Lesson 1</th>
    <th>Lesson 2</th>
  </tr>
@foreach($students as $student)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$student->student_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$student->lessons->lesson1}}</td>
    <td>{{$student->lessons->lesson2}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

This should be work